# Does ActiveRecord touch is concurrent-safe for multiple workers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, concurrency, locking

Imagine I have two workers (W1, W2) running the same job in parallel (sidekiq does not guarantee that a job will run only once, so that might happen).

Job:

```
car.touch(:read_at)
cars = Car.where.not(read_at: nil).order(read_at: :asc).limit(1)
send_user_email if cars.include?(car)
```

The non concurrent version of the problem:

- 19:00:01: W1 touches `read_at`.
- 19:00:02: W1 queries cars, get the most old `car` with `not read_at.nil?`.
- 19:00:03: W1 sends e-mail to user.
- 19:00:04: W2 touches `read_at`.
- 19:00:05: W2 queries cars, get the most old `car` with `not read_at.nil?`.
- 19:00:06: W2 returns, no e-mail sent.
- User gets 1 e-mail.

The concurrent version of the problem:

- 19:00:01: W1 touches `read_at`. AR sends to the DB a write with `read_at=19:00:01`. W1 is having connection problems with DB and the write has not been executed yet.
- 19:00:02: W2 touches `read_at`. AR sends to the DB a write with `read_at=19:00:02`. W2 has a good connection, DB write is executed.
- 19:00:03: W2 queries cars, get the most old `car` with `not read_at.nil?`.
- 19:00:04: W2 sends e-mail to user, W1 write still hasn't been executed.
- 19:00:05: W1 write is executed to DB.
- 19:00:06: W1 queries cars, get the most old `car` with `not read_at.nil?`. Now car from W1 is the oldest, the write was executed after W2, but since the command was `read_at=19:00:01`, car from W1 will be older than car from W2, with `read_at=19:00:02`.
- 19:00:07: W1 sends e-mail to user.
- User gets 2 e-mails.

Is this case (concurrent version) possible to happen?
If so, is there a reason why AR won't use DBs functions to change timestamps with `touch` (for example, postgresql `NOW()`).

Using `NOW()` would make W1 `read_at` to be newer than W2 `read_at`, always.

Answer (score 0):

A good reason (if not the main one) why Rails does not use database native functions is that your database know nothing about which timezone your Rails application is using.

Once you can [configure a timezone](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html) to something other than the one your database server is, whenever you call `car.touch(:read_at)`, Rails needs to tell your database what exactly will be persisted there.

Another thing to have in mind is that your workers should be [idempotent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence). In other words, you should make your code aware of these possible race conditions and protect yourself against them. One solution, as you may already have in mind, is adding proper locks to your database transactions.

Comment: Rails, by default, stores datetime as UTC, right? It could still use db functions as UTC with no problem. When using `touch` I understand that I would like to set the time to right now, otherwise I would use `update` to set a specific timestamp. Regarding idempotence, in that particular case the race condition would not interfere and locking here could stop the intended parallelism of the solution (but yes, jobs always idempotent and locking could be a solution, in expense of parallelism).

Comment: Yes, it stores `datetime` as `UTC` by default, but it's configurable and they need to keep it consistent when your application is configured to use another timezone.

Let's say your application is configured to timezone `CET` and your database server is configured to use `BRT` timezone. How can you make `datetime` attributes consistent in this case if you use native database `NOW()` functions?

It makes no sense to do `datetime` conversions in a database level once you have a that already implemented inside the framework and you can simply use ruby objects for that.